# How to use a Geojson layer as a background mask?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, layers, tilemill, mapbox

I have some Geojson neighborhood shapes that I am using to create a small multiples chart.

They are like this:

[image]

I want to give them backgrounds for the area they represent. I want the streets and buildings to appear but only within the shapes.

What is the best way to try and achieve this?

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Comment: So the issue with this type of visualization is it's the shapes on top of the background. I'm looking for the background within the shapes, everything masked behind it. And I'm looking for it to only appear within the each shape projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [compositing operations](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/comp-op/), possibly [dst-in](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/comp-op/#dst-in).  Your carto might look something like this:

```
  #neighborhoods {
    line-color: #ccc;
    polygon-opacity: 1;
    polygon-comp-op: dst-in;
  }
```